# Exception thrown when trying to deserialize an empty dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization, binaryformatter

I am encountering a weird error while trying to deserialize a dictionary that is contained inside my game's save file.

The error I receive is:

> **System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException:** 'The keys for this hashtable do not exist.'

The save file is generated by serializing a struct to a file with a `BinaryFormatter`.

```
[Serializable]
public struct SaveData
{
    public Dictionary<int, float> LevelClearTimes { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }
    public int LevelsCleared { get; set; }
}

...

protected bool Save(SaveData data)
{
    try
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(filename);
        bf.Serialize(file, this);
        file.Close();
    }
    catch { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

Serialization is working as intended without an error, although when deserializing the data from a different assembly, a SerializationException is thrown, but *only if an empty dictionary was serialized previously*.

Since I am trying to deserialize from a different assembly, I used a custom SerializationBinder to avoid getting an exception.

```
class BindChanger : System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type typeToDeserialize = null;
        string currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
        typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, currentAssembly));
        return typeToDeserialize;
    }
}

...

protected void Load(string file)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Binder = new BindChanger();

    FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filename);
    object binaryData = bf.Deserialize(file);     // the error is thrown here
    SaveData data = (SaveData)binaryData;

    ...
}
```

Oddly enough, when trying to deserialize the data from the original assembly where it was saved from, there is no error.

---

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

---

**Edit:** Here's the binary content that won't be deserialized.

```
    ÿÿÿÿ          Assembly-CSharp   SaveData    <LevelClearTimes>k__BackingField<PlayerName>k__BackingField<PlayerID>k__BackingField<LevelsCleared>k__BackingField  áSystem.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Single, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]            PlayerS›—T       áSystem.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Single, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]   VersionComparerHashSize
KeyValuePairs  ‘System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]             
   ‘System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

Comment: Can you post the binary content  that won't deserialize?

Comment: @Dan Edited it in.

Comment: Please note that until you have successfully **deserialized** the data you should never assume the **serialization** "works perfectly". By definition, you don't know what the root cause is yet.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I am assuming that the serialization is working as intended, because the error never happens when deserializing **inside the same assemly as it was serialized inside**. The error only appears when trying to deserialize the data from another assembly.

Comment: Yes, and it is most likely a problem there as well, I'm just saying that until you've deserialized the data, the data itself might be the problem, stemming from the serialization process. The fact that the serialization process didn't crash doesn't mean it produced the correct data.

Comment: I'm assuming the type that is serialized/deserialized is in a common assembly available to both projects, and that you haven't redefined the type? Meaning, I'm assuming you don't have a copy of `SaveData` in both the project that serialized and the project that deserializes, but instead that you have a third assembly/project where that type is declared?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I just skipped that thought since the deserialization worked without problems until I tried porting it to another assembly.
Also, both assemblies contain seperate copies of the `SaveData` struct, thats why I had to use the custom SerializationBinder.

Comment: You could try this: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1101106/how-to-serialize-across-assemblies-with-the-binary  as its almost certainly a problem with the cross assembly serialization

Comment: If that doesn't work, you may need to just specify your own binary format for the object, as it might be packing/padding/ all sorts of issues that you can't really resolve within the c# binaryformatter.  Especially given you are using different copies of the struct.

Comment: @Dan Yeah, that won't work aswell. I guess I'll have to do as you said, thanks for your help!